# symfony2: pseudo locale (auto-)detection

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have googling this for weeks now and i can't find a nice answer and uique way to do this.
I have a symfony2 application that is using FOSUserBundle. The app is available in different languages.

What i would like is to have an unique way to handle the locale detection. Since it has been moved from the session to the request i don't see a clear way to achieve that.

step a) user is not logged, maybe 1st time we saw it. Take the locale from the request header Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6 (for instance). Serve the user a localized version of login page

step b) user is now loggued in. of course we still serve him is prefered language based on the same header

So far i have done this using ResponseListner but it seems it won't work for the 1st request  and have troubles with the FOSuser login page.

Any help with samples would be very appreciated.

Comment: This is really wide open. Can you show us the exact issue you are facing? Any error messages?

Comment: No error message. It's more an advice on Design Best Practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuneticsLocaleBundle is great for that: https://github.com/lunetics/LocaleBundle

It allows you to create a custom Locale Guesser:
https://github.com/lunetics/LocaleBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/guesser.md

Comment: I don't know why casperOne is closing this as "vague". I think questions like this as what is the state of the art way of doing things are really lacking on SO. Nevermind the answer was good and helped me a lot added to this link (http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1263289/php/bibliotheques-frameworks/symfony2/doctrine2/fosuserbundle-translate-problem/). Many thanks to hacfi !

Comment: By the way symfony is breaking thinks that were working in 2.1 and that enduser for some theorical consideration (locale is based on one uri and not on one session sorry guys, we made a mistake !!!!)